# What are good applications of the ZVex Fuzz Factory

Tags: electric-guitar, guitar-effects

I have recently come into the possession of a [ZVex Fuzz Factory](http://zvex.com/fuzz.html). I hear that this fuzz pedal has a ton of applications beyond using it as a standard fuzz effect.

What are some of its normal uses?

ie. Under *x* control parameters the pedal behaves like *y* with the usual application of *z*.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the answer to this question is subjective, but consider the following video for a demonstration of this thing's power. I love my Fuzz Factory. Super unique.